# Does $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

For any $x\in \Bbb R$, $h(x)\le f(x)\le g(x)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}(g(x)-h(x))=0$. Then does $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ exist?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you think? What does your heart tell you? Or your imagination? Try to visualize the situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're familiar with the Squeeze Theorem, then you know that $\lim_{x}h(x)=\lim_{x}g(x)$ (exists, is finite) implies $\lim_{x}f(x)$ exists and is equal to the former. Your condition is weaker. So for example $h(x)=g(x)=f(x)=x$ satisfies the problem assumption but clearly the limit is infinite. Or take $g(x)=h(x)=f(x)=(-1)^{[x]}$ where the limit doesn't exist at all.

Comment: "the limit doesn't exist" Should not be correct. But seeing that we can take $g$ and $h$ to be a little less likeable and we get what you say.

Comment: One can also take $f(x)=h(x)=g(x)=sin(x)$ and $x$ tends to infinity. The limit do not exists (even finite nor infinite for the three functions)

Comment: @AlexR: what if we take $g>h$ (except in the limit) and both g and h are differentiable everywhere? Does this still hold?